# Error after webpack upgrade from 2 to 3

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I have upgraded webpack from 2.5.1 to 3.6. All went well in webpack dev server mode but failing in webpack build. I observed following error.

`ERROR in chunk main [entry]
[name].[chunkhash].js
'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (42:6)
|   if (false) {
|     module.hot.accept('./reducers', function () {
|       import('./reducers').then(function (reducerModule) {
|         var createReducers = reducerModule.default;
|         var nextReducers = createReducers(store.asyncReducers);`

Following are the packages upgraded.
[image]
[image]

What would have triggered the error? I have set babel loader correctly which works fine with 2.5 webpack version.

*Update*: If i remove `new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin()` I don't get that error. Looks like chunk files are having es6 code which babel-parser is not parsing. How I can configure webpack to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can import your in top level

```
import reducers from './reducers'

if (false) {
  module.hot.accept('./reducers', function () {
    reducers.then(function (reducerModule) {
      var createReducers = reducerModule.default;
      var nextReducers = createReducers(store.asyncReducers);
```

or

```
if (false) {
  module.hot.accept('./reducers', function () {
    require('./reducers').default.then(function (reducerModule) {
      var createReducers = reducerModule.default;
      var nextReducers = createReducers(store.asyncReducers);
```

Comment: This is dynamic import feature I am using. What ever you suggested makes it static import.